# How to reset yield from within a generator in PHP

Tags: php, reset, yield, yield-from

I am trying to setting up a **coupled yield function**. But when the function is called the second time, the **integrated yield from is not reset**.

I think the simplest way is to show using an example:

#### Code Example

PHP

```
class GeneratorTest
{

    public function generatorA() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }


    // Generators can yield from other generators
    public function generatorB() {
        yield from $this->generatorA();  // << why is this not reset?

        for($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) {
            yield chr(65 + $i);
        }
    }

}


$gen = new GeneratorTest();

echo "Test 1 from Generator B<br>";
foreach ($gen->generatorB() as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}

echo "Test 2 from Generator B<br>";
print_r(iterator_to_array($gen->generatorB()));
```

#### Expected?

I expected the output of "Test 2" to be identical to "Test 1". But actually it seems that the yield from generator is not reset when used.

#### Edit / Important:

Like noted by @Ganesh Wagh: Calling the generator in a second "for-each" works perfectly. The problem really only occurs, when calling "iterator_to_array"! Is this the expected behavior.

I tried to reset generatorA at the end of generatorB like this:

PHP

```
public function generatorB() {
    yield from $this->generatorA();

    for($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) {
        yield chr(65 + $i);
    }
    $this->generatorA()->reset();
}
```

But to no avail.

Question: Is this the expected behavior? What do I have to do to reset the "inner" generator?

Comment: it's sounds like there is nothing to do with a needed reset but from the `iterator_to_array` function which never take the first generator into account somehow, I do not know why by the way. https://www.tehplayground.com/bQW1DS4sLsmMj51N . EDIT : well if you use `iterator_to_array` with false as second parameter it works as expected. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

Comment: Basically, the second generator erase the fisrt one in the `iterator_to_array` because the have the same keys, so just change `iterator_to_array($gen->generatorB())` to `iterator_to_array($gen->generatorB(), false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit goes to @Frankich! (Second comment)

The problem was, that "iterator_to_array" evaluated the keys of the generator.

So a generator silently returns the keys of the used generator (yield from):

```php
echo "Test 1 from Generator B\n";
foreach ($gen->generatorB() as $key => $item) {
    echo $key . '=>' .  $item . "\n";
}
```

Results in:

```
1=>1
2=>2
...
0=>A
1=>B
2=>C
...
```

So the keys in:
`iterator_to_array($gen->generatorB()))` where overwritten (like pointed out by @Frankich)!

and only:
`iterator_to_array($gen->generatorB()), false)` prevented that.

Thx for the input!