# Attempting to proceed to `->next()` from a generator enters infinite loop

Tags: php

My current use case is I have a `Generator` that takes an iterable and uses `yield from` to return everything from it ([similar to the example in the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#example-337)). I have two examples below.

In this example, I am manually iterating through the Generator using Iterator methods: `rewind()`, `valid()`, `current()`, and `next()`. This example leads into an infinite loop and I never reach the `var_dump` call.

```php
<?php

$arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
$itr = new ArrayIterator($arr);
    
function q() {
    global $itr;
    
    yield from $itr;
}

$a = [];

q()->rewind();
while (q()->valid()) {
    $a[q()->key()] = q()->current();
    
    q()->next();
}

var_dump($a); // I never reach this
```

In this example, I have a normal call to `iterator_to_array()` and it successfully completes.

```php
<?php

$arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
$itr = new ArrayIterator($arr);
    
function q() {
    global $itr;
    
    yield from $itr;
}

$a = iterator_to_array(q());
var_dump($a);
```

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56983670/how-to-reset-yield-from-within-a-generator-in-php) but it's not quite the answer I'm looking for since that question ends up using `iterator_to_array()`. Similarly, the PHP docs advise using `iterator_to_array` with the `use_keys` parameter. But I'd like to make the while loop work if that's possible.

What am I doing wrong in the first example that is causing me to enter an infinite loop?

Comment: Every time you call `q()` you're getting a new generator, not continuing the previous generator. You should assign `q()` to a variable and reuse that.

Comment: @Barmar I have been hitting my head against the wall on this for a while. You're absolutely right! `q()` is returning a new generator every time and storing it in a variable solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into the same problem I did, thanks to [Barmar in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70676438/attempting-to-proceed-to-next-from-a-generator-enters-infinite-loop/70715306#comment124942656_70676438) for solving it! In my use case, I'm creating a new generator each time I call `q()`, which meant I was never moving forward in the same instance.

Assigning the generator to a variable solves my problem,

```php
<?php

$arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
$itr = new ArrayIterator($arr);
    
function q() {
    global $itr;
    
    yield from $itr;
}

$a = [];
$g = q();

$g->rewind();
while ($g->valid()) {
    $a[$g->key()] = $g->current();
    
    $g->next();
}

var_dump($a); // I never reach this
```